# Rails 3.1.1 and Cucumber - Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have git a little problem running Cucumber. When using cucumber I get the following results:

```
    Yanniss-MacBook:rechnungen yannis$ cucumber
Using the default profile...
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date.
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper. (RuntimeError)
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn/autorun/minitest.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-rails-1.1.1/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/yannis/Sites/rechnungen/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/yannis/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
Yanniss-MacBook:rechnungen yannis$
```

Minitest is installed:

```
Yanniss-MacBook:rechnungen yannis$ gem list minitest

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

minitest (2.6.1)
```

And Google doesn't return anything... I need your help...

Thanks a lot, 
Tom

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I fixed this by applying a **Pessimistic Version Constraint** to `turn` in my `Gemfile`:

```
group :test do
  gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3'
end
```

Update: The version constraint should no longer be necessary, according to [a maintainer](https://github.com/TwP/turn/issues/59):

> Technically .. MiniTest is an optional dependency .. It would not normally be an issue .. but the MiniTest shipped with Ruby is well behind the latest version of MiniTest, which Turn needs.  Since almost everyone has moved to MiniTest now, I will simply add it as a dependency.

I haven't verified the above because I use rspec now.

Comment: I had the same problem in my gem and besides downgrading turn to 0.8.2 in gemspec I also had to uninstall version 0.8.3 - for some version rake still loaded it, even when 0.8.2 was required.

Comment: Thanks Jared! I ran into this just now and your suggestion here helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm new on Ruby on Rails.
I had the same problem and what I did to solve this was:
- I put in Gemfile the following: gem 'minitest'

Heber

Comment: I don't like the way minitest injects itself into all my rake tasks and even the console output, so I don't really care for this option

Comment: Good enough to solve my problem. I'm new to Rails to, so would love to understand why this was happening.

Comment: Cucumber >=1.2 seems to require minitest

Comment: "New in Ruby 1.9, MiniTest is now the standard unit testing framework supplied with Ruby." source: The Pickaxe book, p. 798. So MiniTest is already there, just not the version required by `turn`.