# Rails Generate throwing Minitest error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal

I am just starting to learn Rails and I'm creating my first project. In my Gemfile i've added:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'turn'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'growl_notify'
end
```

And run `bundle`. All is going fine so far.

I tried running `rails g` to see if my packages were installed but I was faced with the following error:

```
GarysMBA:glecto swally_1991$ rails g
gem install minitest
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.4/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- minitest/unit (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.4/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.4/lib/turn.rb:13:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.4/lib/turn.rb:13
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/swally_1991/Desktop/glecto/config/application.rb:13
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:24
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I have searched my config but I can't find any references to **Minitest** anywhere? Has anyone came across this problem before? Or can point me in the right direction of fixing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
group :test do
  gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3'
end
```

This should help you, read more [Rails 3.1.1 and Cucumber - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719114/rails-3-1-1-and-cucumber-error)