# rails command failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had/) which covers TDD using rspec, capybara etc. I added the following to my Gemfile:

```
group :test, :development do
    gem 'turn'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'growl_notify'
end
```

Ran `bundle install` and now get:

```
juco@jucoiMac ~/Desktop/rails-test $ rails s
    gem install minitest
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- minitest/unit (LoadError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
        from /Users/juco/Desktop/rails-test/config/application.rb:7
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

When I try to execute any rails commands including `rails server`. This has been [posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100522/rails-insecure-world-writable-dir-library-ruby-gems-1-8-in-path-mode-040777), but went unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn gem version-

```
 group :test do
      gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3'
    end
```

Followed from: [Minitest Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989609/rails-generate-throwing-minitest-error).

Answer (score 1):

`turn`gem is for minitest. Seems you are using rspec so you got an incompatibility.